# Raven DB Multiple Spatial Indexes

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to get my model to work with multiple spatial indexes. Basically, I have a Route with a source and destination. I want to search my Routes where both Source is WithinRadiusOf and Destination is WithinRadiusOf....but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have my indexes defined...but I only know how to use 1 in a single query.

```
 Map = routes => from r in routes select new { _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(r.Source.Location.Latitude, r.Source.Location.Longitude) };

Map = routes => from r in routes select new { _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(r.Destination.Location.Latitude, r.Destination.Location.Longitude) };


session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Route>("Routes/BySource")
            .WithinRadiusOf(...);
```

...but I'm not sure how to get the second spatial index into the mix?

I could materialize and do a join in memory afterwards...but I'm wondering if there is a way to get this into the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't provide a way to do spatial queries on more than one point.

Comment: so your recommendation would be to do an in-memory join after the fact?